# Strange home bar appearance in SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui

I have a View that has some VStacks and ZStacks (top bar, carousel, detail view with if condition).

This code changes fullscreen/not fullscreen appearance:

```swift
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(viewModel.currentItem != nil ? .all : [])
```

But even without .all activated I have a strange bottom Home bar appearance like there is a gradient/shadow overlay on it:

[image]

What could cause this and how to avoid this?

P.S. I also noticed in my UI hierarchy that HostingViewController is a subview of the UIDropShadowView.

P.P.S. It also doesn't go when navigation to other view with NavigationLink

Comment: I've seen this frequently. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an issue, it should be like that, since we have no touch id in new iPhone models, that things play as kind of help in Screen. And when you use `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` in your code, you get access to under area and back area of that shape for Color works!

That shape is used for Swipe up to go iPhone main screens.

Look at the iPhone 8, it has touch, and look at iPhone 11, No touch ID!

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I mean not the Home bar itself, but some kind of gradient/shadow above it. Sometimes it is normal and sometimes it's kind of covered with something.

Comment: I know it really does happen sometimes but no big issue.